# Factory class creates untyped objects

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a factory. It's purpose is to facilitate dependency injection. It looks something like:

```
import SomeImportantObject from "./SomeImportantObject"
import DataInterface from "./DataInterface"

class NoodleFactory {
  this.dependency: SomeImportantObject
  constructor(dependency: SomeImportantObject) {
    // Dependencies.
    this.dependency = dependency;
  }

  create(data: DataInterface) {
    return new Noodle(data, this.dependency);
  }
}
```

I was creating a test for it to ensure that it is correctly creating objects. The test is very similar to:

```
data = {
  // Data.
}

mockDependency = "a mocked dependency."

testNoodleFactory = new NoodleFactory(mockDependency);

const expected = new Noodle(data, mockDependency);
const actual = testNoodleFactory.create(data);

test("Factory creates noodles", () => {
  expect(actual).toMatchObject(expected);
});
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
    @@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
    - Noodle {
    + Object {
```

All internal data matches.

What is causing the object types to be different?

Comment: This whole example is full of implicit anys and undefined references (i.e. type errors) but you're concerned about type safety? What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: The example is a quick representation of the actual code. I'll make it more robust.

Comment: The [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEByD28AmICm0DeAoa1jwDsIAXAJwFdhj5SAKMAGmgCMBKTHXaTgXxz6yhIMBMjQAxMFRoBPDrgAO5ZiACWwaElQLUBLQWCrUEANyd8RMpWp0I8ALaoAItt37Dx9ti7QA9L+gXHT1dDwgAOk5cYgALVQitYPcjGABeaDtHILdQlLNcAVxgUlQwYlRaJDKwLyjoEuJyUgJoAlQAdzhEFAqq4kZoWPjwxJyDFNZ86D4BCxJoADMNdLbO0R7JaVIZWgBmScFCeYXVUnmVjq6xCoBWJgA2AHYDueIM1AskaHSl8OLS8q0ACMACYDkA) suggests that the factory's create method does indeed return the correct type. Jest's `toMatchObject` is about matching *subsets* of object properties. I'll repeat: what is your actual question?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the test is completely superfluous as it merely replicates the work the type checker is already doing. Even after the edit I still don't understand what you're after here. You just want to make sure it's a Noodle instance?

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the question and add typing.

Comment: Yes, I want to be sure the NoodleFactory is returning a Noodle instance.

Comment: Well it is (see the link in my comment above), but again, that's superfluous. That's what the *type checker is for*. Don't clutter your test suite with useless tests. But yeah `toMatchObject` does not do what you seem to think it does. Make sure you read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `console.log` to inspect what gets returned from each call.

Reasoning about your code (without executing it), I can see no explanation for this.

I had a quick look over the Jest source code. The object matcher is here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/matchers.ts#L878

It uses the `iterableEquality` and `subsetEquality` tests from here:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/utils.ts

`toMatchObject` checks that it is an object, that they have the same constructor (that looks like the failing test), and then that the object you compare it with has a subset of the keys of the object you are testing.

I would look at the constructor of the object returned from the Noodle factory in the first instance.

If you create an MRE in a GitHub repo, I'll check it out and trace the code execution (or you could do that - just inject `console.log` statements in the Jest in the `node_modules`).

Comment: Hey, glad this helped you - what did it turn out to be?